# Docker-compose exclude from volume and copy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

A few lines from **docker-compose.yml**

```
   volumes:
      - ./yii-application:/app/yii-application
      - /app/yii-application/common/config/
```

First line adds to the volume an entire application.
The second one  makes some sort of exclude of config folder, so I do not need my config from host machine.

A few lines from **Dockerfile**

```
COPY ./config-${APP_ENV}/common /app/yii-application/common/config
```

Instead of COPY I tried

```
RUN cp -a /app/config-${APP_ENV}/common/. /app/yii-application/common/config
```

It does not work either.

Comment: Try changing the order and see if it helps

Comment: I changed the order of the  volumes declaration. The same.

Comment: Then I doubt this can work

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue in the order of the commands that are being executed:

1. When you are building and image with Dockerfile, you are coping the code inside dir `/app/yii-application/common/config`.
2. Then, you are mounting a volume: `volumes: /app/yii-application/common/config/`
   and overwriting the existing dir with an empty dir that serves as a volume.

You need to work around that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the config files out of volume directory.
So, now the volume looks like this

```
   volumes:
      - ./yii-application:/app/yii-application
```

Config files in

```
./
```